# Kohana Exception not clear

Tags: php, permissions, kohana

I'm using Kohana and when running index.php page, I've got following error:

`Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory a:0:{} must be writable`

**a:0:{}**
what is it?

Everything is writeable: I'm working under linux debian squeeze and ls-l done on every folder and subfolder remove every doubt..
I've checked pages involved and indicated:

`MODPATH/pajas/init.php`

`SYSPATH/classes/kohana/core.php [ 562 ] » require_once()`

`DOCROOT/index.php [ 96 ] » require(arguments)`

but everything seems to be ok..

that **Directory a:0:{}** is completely dark for me and I'll hope someone could help me looking for solution in the right way

Thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: My guess it's the `APPPATH.cache` and `APPPATH.logs` directories, no idea what `a:0:{}` is. My guess is it's garbage from some empty config variable. Vaguely remember kohana looking for a table named `a:0:{}_table_name` because I was getting a config var (table_prefix) the wrong way.

Comment: What Kohana version are you running? Can you show the Kohana::modules() code block? For the meaning of 'a:0:{}': http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f62c5cd5ced39fa3134baed223ec78fb58dbaca7

Comment: Thank you both :) Kohana::modules() code block:
`APPPATH/bootstrap.php [ 109 ] » Kohana_Core::modules(arguments)
0 
array(5) (
    "auth" => string(54) "/var/www-data/basilicatasconti/carsharing/modules/auth"
    "cache" => string(55) "/var/www-data/basilicatasconti/carsharing/modules/cache"
    "database" => string(58) "/var/www-data/basilicatasconti/carsharing/modules/database"
    "image" => string(55) "/var/www-data/basilicatasconti/carsharing/modules/image"
    "pajas" => string(55) "/var/www-data/basilicatasconti/carsharing/modules/pajas"
)`
Kohana version is 3.1.3.1
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you recently add a module name `pajas`? Based on the error messages you posted, [`core.php`](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1/master/classes/kohana/core.php#L562) appears to be failing on the init script of a "pajas" module.

Assuming [this](https://github.com/lillem4n/kohana-module-pajas) is the "pajas" module you are using, a quick look at the `init` script shows it attempts to locate a path from the configuration name '`user_content.dir`', and if the path is not writeable it raises an exception with the message 'Directory :dir must be writable' ([source](https://github.com/lillem4n/kohana-module-pajas/blob/master/init.php#L19)).

Check your configs for a file named `user_content.php` which should have a key name `dir`. By default, it should be in `{MODPATH}/{pajas_directory}/config/user_content.php` (default example [here](https://github.com/lillem4n/kohana-module-pajas/blob/master/config/user_content.php)), but you should also check if it is overriden somewhere (usually in `APPPATH/config/`. Next, make sure that the default path `APPPATH/user_content` (or whatever your overriden path is) exists.

Comment: Yeah. There's pajas but everything seems to be ok.. Surely there's something wrong.. APPPath is ok.. I've created user_content folder with right permissions too. DB settings are corrects.. Maybe I'm checking something else somewhere.. Thanks for help, guys

Comment: Done and re-done. But nothing changes. I've got Pajas and I think I've done everything in correct way.. nothing at all.. still got problem

Comment: $config->load('user_content.dir') return nothing.. but debugging with Kohana doing `echo Debug::vars(Kohana::$config->load('user_content'));`
I've obtained 
`object Config_File(2) {
    public driver => object Config_File(0) {
    }
    public dir => string(66) "/var/www-data/basilicatasconti/carsharing/application/user_content"
}`
I can't understand what does it mean...

Comment: Try the debug output again with the following lines (note there is no `load` method call): 
`Debug::vars(Kohana::config('user_content'))` & `Debug::vars(Kohana::config('user_content.dir'))`. Post the exact output as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: Have you ever successfully used the `pajas` module with this version of Kohana? It appears to me that it is not compatible. If you look at the [3.1 docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/files/config) you can see that they use `Kohana::config()`, where in [3.2 docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/config) you see the `Kohana::$config->load()` usage. You might want to try and open an issue on the [`pajas` issue tracker](https://github.com/lillem4n/kohana-module-pajas/issues?state=open) since their README states that 3.1 is supported but it doesn't look very active.

Comment: It's the first time for me I user kohana and pajas.. good idea.. I'll try. Thank you

Comment: that's why!
https://github.com/lillem4n/kohana-module-pajas/issues/21

module deprecated! This for complete and close this question. Thanks everyone. Anne